# Solution of third order ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, frobenius-method

I consider the following ODE
$$
f'''(x) = B f''(x) + (Ce^x+D)f'(x) + (Ee^x+F)f(x) 
$$
for some constants $B$, $C$, $D$, $E$, $F$ and $x\in [0, \infty)$.

This ODE seems to be complicated so I used WolframAlpha (https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=f%27%27%27%28x%29+%3D+B+f%27%27%28x%29+%2B+%28C+e%5Ex+%2B+D%29f%27%28x%29+%2B+%28E+e%5Ex+%2B+F%29+f%28x%29) to find the general form of its solution.

My problem is that I am not sure if the solution that WolframAlpha returns is correct.
Can anyone suggest me how can I find the general form of this solution or which software (similar to WolframAlpha) I can use to find this solution.

Comment: What did you expect? I got the same using *Mathematica*

Comment: Note that Wolfram Alpha doesn't know that $x \in [0, \infty)$. Maybe this could be a reason.

Answer (score 1):

Let $t=e^x$ ,

Then $\dfrac{df}{dx}=\dfrac{df}{dt}\dfrac{dt}{dx}=e^x\dfrac{df}{dt}=t\dfrac{df}{dt}$

$\dfrac{d^2f}{dx^2}=\dfrac{d}{dx}\left(t\dfrac{df}{dt}\right)=\dfrac{d}{dt}\left(t\dfrac{df}{dt}\right)\dfrac{dt}{dx}=\left(t\dfrac{d^2f}{dt^2}+\dfrac{df}{dt}\right)t=t^2\dfrac{d^2f}{dt^2}+t\dfrac{df}{dt}$

$\dfrac{d^3f}{dx^3}=\dfrac{d}{dx}\left(t^2\dfrac{d^2f}{dt^2}+t\dfrac{df}{dt}\right)=\dfrac{d}{dt}\left(t^2\dfrac{d^2f}{dt^2}+t\dfrac{df}{dt}\right)\dfrac{dt}{dx}=\left(t^2\dfrac{d^3f}{dt^3}+3t\dfrac{d^2f}{dt^2}+\dfrac{df}{dt}\right)t=t^3\dfrac{d^3f}{dt^3}+3t^2\dfrac{d^2f}{dt^2}+t\dfrac{df}{dt}$

$\therefore t^3\dfrac{d^3f}{dt^3}+3t^2\dfrac{d^2f}{dt^2}+t\dfrac{df}{dt}=Bt^2\dfrac{d^2f}{dt^2}+Bt\dfrac{df}{dt}+(Ct+D)t\dfrac{df}{dt}+(Et+F)f$

$t^3\dfrac{d^3f}{dt^3}+(3-B)t^2\dfrac{d^2f}{dt^2}-(Ct^2+(B+D-1)t)\dfrac{df}{dt}-(Et+F)f=0$

Seek for power series solution